# PHP generated SVG file is having head and body tag added in browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, svg

I have a dynamically generated SVG embedded in a HTML page. It is displaying but has undesired horizontal and verticle scroll bars, v. annoying! By inspecting the element in Chrome browser I see that it has a <head> and <body> tag, Not normal for an SVG! If I change the ''data'' attribute to include a traditional static SVG, no head or body tag is added in the browser.

I am serving SVG XML from a PHP page on an Apache server and embedding it as an object in the markup as folllows:

```
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" data="mapphp.svg"></object>
```

The browser is obviously detecting that this is not a traditional SVG file and I can only assume it is treating it as Content-Type:text/html and adding the head and body tag to standardise what it thinks is badly written markup.

I have even tried masking the PHP file with .htaccess and overwriting the headers with mod_headers.c

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} mapphp.svg [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ map.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "mapphp\.svg$">
    Header set ETag "813c0-3a0-4e7c49319ad82"
    Header unset Content-Type
    Header unset X-Powered-By
    Header unset Server
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Yet it still seems to treat my SVG as a HTML document and gives it a <head> and <body> tag.

P.S. I am going to bed upon posting this so please don't be offended if I do not respond until tomorrow. I will greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `map.php` include the following header `header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");` before any output is made.

Comment: I don't think OP has any file with the name `mapphp.svg` but `header` function will still be needed in `map.php`

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked. So just to clarify the cause of the problem; Is it fair to state that the Chrome browser will add a head and body tag to documents only when it receives headers with Content-Type: text/html and does not detect a head and body tag?

Comment: By the way, just to clarify, it was not changing the extension to .php that solved it. The data parameter of my `object` tag is still set to `mapphp.svg` in my working version because my .htaccess rules successfully mask it to the PHP file. The step that actually solved it was adding `header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");`. It was bugging me to think that this post may have lead a noob to think the file extension was the root cause. I have painful memories of being a noob, lead astray by supposedly harmless, off-topic comments in forum posts. Once again, thanks for your speedy answer.

Comment: @rosscowar Thanks. I did not realise the answer could be edited. Done now.